# Error Handling when running a CSV Import to MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to automate the import of a CSV file into MySQL. I thought I could run a PHP file as a cronjob on my server as PHPMyAdmin doesn't have Events enabled (and can't be due to webhost).

I've been trying with LOAD DATA Syntax as seems popular when I google the issue and come across the fifty million threads on Stack Overflow. However, I'm having trouble debugging my own configuration and frustrated that I can't find a way for it to show me errors to help work out what I'm doing wrong.

I know my CSV file variable is correct as I have a code to check that and it passes (I've also purposely made it fail and it fails, so definitely working):

```
$file = fopen($csvfile,"r");

if (!$file) {
        echo "<h1>bachHa'!</h1><p>Error opening data file.</p>\n";
        exit;
}
```

So, I know I've located my CSV file and I'm passing that correctly to LOAD DATA, but after that, who knows, all I know is I don't get anything in my database after it runs:

```
$import = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$csvfile'
     INTO TABLE test_upload
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
     IGNORE 1 LINES
    (response_id,date_submitted,status,q1,q5_text,q2,q3,q4_1,q4_2,q4_3,q4_4,q4_5,StoreName);
eof;

$conn->query($import);
```

The column headers are accurate, my datafile is aligned with them, empty columns are allowed NULL.

I've looked through [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) but can't find a way to grab the errors to display in my PHP file, echo'ing `$import` looks fine and `$conn` doesn't echo anything (not sure if it should, I'm not a programmer and just trying to bodge my way through this).

Example of the csv file:

```
"Response ID","Date Submitted","Status","Q01","Q05","Q02","Q03","Q04_01","Q04_02","Q04_03","Q04_04","Q04_05","StoreName"
"62","2019/05/06 16:43:59","Complete","8","","8","No","Very good","Good","Very good","Good","Very good","Store A"
"63","2019/05/06 16:45:36","Complete","10","I had a very nice experience with a lady called Karen she was very helpful","10","Yes","Very good","Good","Good","Good","Very good","Store C"
```

Any help is greatly received!

Comment: Assuming that $conn is a PDO, you can call $conn->errorInfo() to get an array of elements describing the last error.

Comment: Ah, no @jpheldson, $conn is `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);` - will try a PDO, not done one of those before.

Comment: In that case, check out the contents of $conn->error_list (also an array) after the query fails.

Comment: You also might want to check this out: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-local-infile-handler.php

Comment: Thanks @jpheldson but your first response was enough, using this https://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/pdo-select-query-fetch (FETCH_ASSOC) as an example, I switched over to PDO and the `$conn->errorInfo()` (which I displayed to screen by wrapping it in a `var_dump($conn->errorInfo());` ) gave me **"Access denied for user 'my_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" ** so that's somewhere I can work from, it could be my host doesn't allow the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE commands.

Comment: That particular error generally indicates an authentication issue.  You might want to run a simple query like "SELECT 1" as a sanity check to make sure you have your connection.

Comment: Thank you, I can select so I'm presuming it's not allowed, I had read some providers do not allow this (they also have Events disabled in PHPMyAdmin which was going to be my first call of importing the file).

Thanks for you help, I'll take it up with my host to see if I can get the option enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jpheldson for the help with `$conn->errorInfo()` to get the error message, as suspected in the above comments my provider doesn't allow `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` on shared hosting (nor Events in PHPMyAdmin) so had to find a different way around my problem:

```
include '/php_include/db_details.php';
session_start();
try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo '<h1>bachHa\'!</h1><p>Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage(). '</p>';
}

//set import data file:
foreach (glob("/ftp/raw_survey/*.csv") as $csvfile)

//check we can open it
$file = fopen($csvfile,"r");

if (!$file) {
        echo "<h1>bachHa'!</h1><p>Error opening data file.</p>\n";
        exit;
}

//push it into MySQL
$file = fopen($csvfile, "r");
        fgetcsv($file, 10000, ',', '"'); //cheat to ignore header
        while (($column = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ',', '"')) !== FALSE) {

            $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO test_upload(response_id,date_submitted,status,q1,q2,q3,q4_1,q4_2,q4_3,q4_4,q4_5,q5_text,StoreName)
                   values ('" . $column[0] . "','" . $column[1] . "','" . $column[2] . "','" . $column[3] . "','" . $column[4] . "','" . $column[5] . "','" . $column[6] . "','" . $column[7] . "','" . $column[8] . "','" . $column[9] . "','" . $column[10] . "','" . htmlentities($column[11], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "','" . $column[12] . "')";
            mysqli_real_escape_string(q5_text);
            $result = $conn->query($sqlInsert);

            if (! empty($result)) {
                $type = "Qapla'";
                $message = "CSV Data uploaded into the database";
            } else {
                $type = "bachHa'";
                $message = "Problem in Importing CSV Data";
            }
        }
//var_dump($conn->errorInfo());

//close file now we're done with it
fclose($file);

//transfer from temp upload to main data
        if (! empty($result)) {        
            $sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO data (response_id,date_submitted,status,q1,q2,q3,q4_1,q4_2,q4_3,q4_4,q4_5,q5_text,StoreName)
                SELECT u.response_id,u.date_submitted,u.status,u.q1,u.q2,u.q3,u.q4_1,u.q4_2,u.q4_3,u.q4_4,u.q4_5,u.q5_text,u.StoreName
                FROM test_upload AS u
                WHERE u.`status` = 'Complete' AND u.store_list IS NOT NULL AND u.response_id NOT IN (SELECT response_id FROM data)";
            $result2 = $conn->query($sqlUpdate);

            if (! empty($result2)) {
                $type = "Qapla'";
                $message = "CSV Data uploaded & transferred to main dataset";
            } else {
                $type = "bachHa'";
                $message = "Data uploaded but not imported";
            }
        }

// Verify Load
$sql = "SELECT StoreName AS 'STORE', COUNT(*) AS 'RECORDS' FROM test_upload WHERE `status` = 'Complete' AND store_list IS NOT NULL AND response_id NOT IN (SELECT response_id FROM data) GROUP BY StoreName ORDER BY StoreName";
$verify = $conn->query($sql);

//clear temp
        if (! empty($result2)) {       
            $sqlClear = "DELETE FROM test_upload";
            $result3 = $conn->query($sqlClear);

            if (! empty($result3)) {
                $type = "Qapla'";
                $message = "CSV Data uploaded, transferred to main dataset & temp table cleared";
            } else {
                $type = "bachHa'";
                $message = "Data imported but temp not cleared";
            }
        }   

//disconnect SQL
$conn = null;       
//delete csv to prevent it being re-imported in the future
unlink($csvfile);
?>
<h1><?php echo($type); ?></h1><p><?php echo($message); ?></p>
<table>
        <?php while($row = $verify->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['STORE']. '</td><td>'. $row['RECORDS']. '</td></tr>';
        }?>
</table>
```

This works perfectly fine when opening in the browser and called as a cronjob, so, job done, example placed above to help anyone who comes across this in the future and needs a similar alternative. Using PDO, `htmlentities` on the open text and `mysqli_real_escape_string` so hopefully this is SQL injection proof - if I've missed anything please feel free to tell me why I'm stupid!

Comment: What is "mysqli_real_escape_string(q5_text)" in your while loop trying to accomplish?

Comment: I like generating errors in my log file ; )

I've since removed it, I thought I was adding an extra layer of security, I was not, the `htmlentities()` does enough and coupled with using a PDO I believe I'm relatively safe from SQL injection from what I've been reading.

Comment: With the way you are currently using PDO you are no safer from SQL injection as you would be using any other method. In order to reap the benefits of PDO you need to use parameterized prepared statements.

Comment: Also, you're missing braces on your first foreach statement so you will only ever process at most 1 file with this script. (The last one returned by your call to glob())

Comment: Ahh, I will need to do more reading then - thanks!

The second one is intentional, I only want to grab the most recent file (in testing I'd disabled the delete file and had a few days of data built up)